# Jquery Faq not toggling inside table?

Tags: jquery

I have inserted this script:
As you might be able to tell i am trying to make the Answer cell display on click of the question cell. 
Keep in mind i have a list of these questions and answers.
This doesn't seem to work.

```js
jQuery(".qs").click(function() {
$(this).next(".ans").toggle();
});
```

```css
.ans { display: none; }
```

```html
<div data-foldup="yes" class="bg_faq_content_section">
<h4>App fundamentals</h4>
<div class="questions">
<table class="faqs" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td class="qs"><a>1. How does LenDen Work?</a></td>
<td class="ans">Answer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="qs"><a>2. Different modes of transaction?</a></td>
<td class="ans">Answer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="qs"><a>3. Reliability of donate option?</a></td>
<td class="ans">Answer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="qs"><a>4. What you can sell?</a></td>
<td class="ans">Answer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="qs"><a>5. What you can&#8217;t sell?</a></td>
<td class="ans">Answer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="qs"><a>6. How to disable your account?</a></td>
<td class="ans">Answer</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this *have* to be in a table? Hiding/showing table cells is rather unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```js
jQuery(".qs").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".ans").toggle();
});
```

```css
.ans { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="faqs" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td class="qs"><a>1. Question?</a></td>
<td class="ans">Answer</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Interesting it seems to work here but not on the actual page, ill post more html

Comment: Actually this worked i had to change the $ to jQuery

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(".qs").click(function() {
$(this).next(".ans").toggle();
});
```

```css
.ans { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="faqs" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td class="qs"><a>1. Question?</a></td>
<td class="ans">Answer</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You have forgot to include the jQuery library that;s why it is not working I have added it in the code. You can check the code in working condition now.

Answer (score 0):

simple just call .next():

```
> jQuery(".qs").click(function() {
$(this).next().toggle();
});
```